# Outlook Add In - Determine Item type on ItemSend event

Tags: vsto, add-in

I am trying to determine the item Type or interface type of the current object being sent. For Example, when I click send, I would like my program to determine if the window the button was clicked in was a MailItem, a meeting item or an Inline Response.

Any help would be appreciated, many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was achieved by assigning the Item parameter in the ItemSend event to the corresponding window type as shown below.

```
     currentMail = Item as Outlook.MailItem;
     currentAppointment = Item as Outlook.AppointmentItem;
     currentMeeting = Item as Outlook.MeetingItem;
```